# Android Studio with SQL Server 2012

Tags: android, sql-server, jdbc

I need to make a generic app which can be used by anyone.
App will connect directly to MS SQL server, which will be within intranet/wifi
I donot need to worry about security risk,
I donot want to use web service or anything which we need to do something on server.
I am new and I have tried every option but still can't connect to sql from android studio.

Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
String url = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://192.168.0.7/MYDB;user=android;password=abcd;";
Connection DbConn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);

Please suggest the easiest way to connect, as I said it will be used by different people on different server
I need to connect directly with Dynamics NAV database without any middle tier

Can we connect directly to SQL Server from Android Studio?

Comment: What do you mean `connect to SQL Server from Android Studio`?  What are you trying to do?

Comment: make sure you have ask for and have `use internet` privileges. and check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13921546/connecting-android-to-sql-server-using-jdbc

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your comments

I found this and worked

```
 if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```